# decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy issue

Tags: ios, ios5

Does anyone know whats wrong with this code

```
NSDecimalNumber *quantity = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[item objectForKey:@"Quantity"]];
NSDecimalNumber *price =  [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[item objectForKey:@"Price"]];
NSDecimalNumber *itemTotal = [price decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:quantity];
```

Line 3 throws an exception with error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException', reason: 'NSDecimalNumber overflow exception'
```

Comment: Can you give examples of what numbers / strings are giving you this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess its that the strings you are passing to initWithString are not valid numbers.  Compare quantity and price to [NSDecimalNumber notANumber] before computing itemTotal.

Comment: I feel like an idiot...Thanks both of you David Rönnqvist & dragosaur for pointing in correct direction. I had a "$" symbol appended to price field.